# Why isn't multiselect list showing selected items? MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I moved on and then came back to this, but I am still unable to get it to work.

```
        var companiesList = subcontractRepository.SubcontractCompanies(Subcontract.subcontract_id);
        IEnumerable<Guid> selectedList = companiesList.Select(a => a.Id);
        Companies = new MultiSelectList(companiesList, "Id", "Name", selectedList);
```

In SubcontractRepository.cs

```
    public class SelectCompanyItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectCompanyItem> SubcontractCompanies(Guid id)
    {
        return
            from c in db.companies
            select new SelectCompanyItem
            {
                Name = c.company_name,
                Id = c.company_id
            };
    }
```

View:

```
        <p>
            <label for="Companies">Company:</label>
            <%= Html.ListBox("Companies", Model.Companies) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Companies", "*") %>
        </p>
```

produced html:

```
    <p>
        <label for="Companies">Company:</label>
        <select id="Companies" multiple="multiple" name="Companies"><option value="4cf411d0-e111-488b-822f-ea194951cfda">Second Company</option>
        <option value="1c21e613-a668-4817-bf6d-73befb8c9dbd">Test Company</option>
        </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: So it appears you are trying to select all items in the list, is that right?  Have you looked at the HTML that is produced?

Comment: Yes.  I was trying to simplify it by removing my select criteria and just get it to work selecting all first.  Added the html produced to original post.

Comment: From your html it doesn't seem like selected attribute is being rendered. So check your selectedList values they might not be populated or don't match. Try doing a List<string> for selectedValued and see if it works.

Comment: I checked and the ids in selectedList match those in the rendered html.  I converted to a List<string> and still nothing is selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution.  The ListBox must have a different name from the MultiSelectList.  I renamed the MultiSelectList in my original code, and it works.  I don't want to even begin to think about the amount of time I spent on this!

Comment: This was very a frustrating situation for me as well. Even though my original code had a different name, it wasn't until I gave the list a completely bogus name (i.e., "stupidListBox") and re-ran the code that it started working. I subsequently went back and renamed the list something more appropriate ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this! I know I've run into this before but forgot all about this dumb 'gotcha'...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly work around for now. Set your ViewData with the values you want selected.

```
ViewData["Companies"] = new string[] { "guid-1", "guid-2" };
```

I am still trying to debug and see why this is happening. Suprisingly the Unit test for this use case in the MVC project works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Please let me know if you figure it out.  I have had no luck.

Comment: I discovered the issue.  See my answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, makes sense seems like the helper method finds a ViewData entry for Companies and since it is emtpy it doesn't set any fields as selected. Thanks.